# How to delete a stackLayout that was is associated with a tabButton in a TabBar

Tags: qt, qml

I've created a Qt empty app where the qml code is the below.

What i want to do is i click on the button "add Tab" and create both the tab and the correspondent page. But if i delete (click on the remove Tab) it doesn't get completly removed!
If i click on "add Tab2" button it was supposed to appear the second page.

How can this be solved?

main.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.2
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3
import QtQuick.Controls 2.3
import QtQuick.Window 2.3

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Button{
        id:createButton
        text:"add Tab"
        onClicked: { newTab(1) }
        anchors.right: parent.right
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
    }

    Button{
        text:"remove Tab"
        onClicked: { closeTab() }
        anchors.right: createButton.left
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
    }

    Button{
        id:createButton2
        text:"add Tab2"
        onClicked: { newTab(2) }
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
    }

    function newTab (val) {
        var c = Qt.createComponent("Panel_"+val+".qml")
        var tab1 = c.createObject(content)
        tabBar.addItem(tabButton.createObject(tabBar, {text: "teste", "font.pixelSize": 14} ))
    }

    function closeTab(){
        var _contentData = tabBar.contentData
        for (var i = 0; i < _contentData.length; ++i)
        {
            if( _contentData[i]['contentItem']['text']==="teste"){
                    var _removeItem = tabBar.itemAt(i);
                    tabBar.removeItem(_removeItem);
            }
        }
        tabBar.setCurrentIndex(0)
    }


    header: TabBar {
        id: tabBar
        opacity:0.8
    }

    Component {
        id: tabButton
        TabButton {
            font.pixelSize: 14
        }
    }

    StackLayout {
        id: content
        currentIndex: tabBar.currentIndex
        anchors.fill: parent
    }


}
```

Panel_1.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Item {
        property string title: qsTr("panel1")
    Text{text:"panel1"}    
}
```

Panel_2 qml is the same thing as Panel_1.

Comment: There's something called a [TabView](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-tabview.html) in qml. It seems like a suitable alternative to your current setup. Have you tried it before?

Answer (score 2):

You have removed the corresponding item from the TabButton but not the item corresponding to StackLayout, so you must remove the child with the same index, but when you are removing an item from a list you must iterate from the end to the beginning.

```
function closeTab(){
    var _contentData = tabBar.contentData
    for (var i = _contentData.length -1 ; i >= 0; --i)
    {
        if( _contentData[i]['contentItem']['text']==="teste"){
            var _removeItem = tabBar.itemAt(i);
            tabBar.removeItem(_removeItem);
            content.children[i].destroy()
        }
    }
    tabBar.setCurrentIndex(0)
}
```